# sklearn subset fitted pipeline - reuse for transform

Tags: scikit-learn

I have constructed a pipeline with several steps which takes some time to fit. For debugging I would like to be able to inspect subsets of that pipeline (e.g. {pipe step 1-3}.transform(X)).

I know that I can use Pipe(pipe.named_steps[:3]) to extract a subset and construct a new pipeline from it. Unfortunately I have to refit the pipeline before calling transform on it.

Is there a way to avoid the refit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access subparts of a `Pipeline` object by indexing it like a normal list, e.g. `pipe[:3]`. This will return a new, yet unfitted `Pipeline` instance. Interestingly though, its components are fitted.

In consequence, a check with scikit-learn's [`check_is_fitted`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html) function would raise an error. However, you can nonetheless call `pipe[:3].transform(X)` which will still work if you have fit the whole pipeline before.